# How to remove dashes in a text file

Tags: bash, sed, passwords

I have a text file called employees.txt that I want to create new users from;

```
emily01,home,1992-04-24
john02,work,1990-03-14
```

How do I omit the dashes in the numbers?

This is what I have so far, I can't figure out what I am missing to make it work.

```
     sed 's/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\1\2\3/'
            
        while IFS="," read -r F1 F2 F3;
            do useradd "$F1" -g "$F2" -p "$F3"
    
done < employees.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with `sed`:

```sh
while IFS="," read -r f1 f2 f3; do
   f3=$(echo $f3 | sed 's/-//g')
   sudo useradd "$f1" -g "$f2" -p "$f3"
done < "employees.txt"
```

Comment: you can also use [Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) `f3=${f3//-}` instead of external commands...